# How to retrieve all permissions of a specific model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, permissions

By default each django model has 3 permissions (add, change, delete). In a model I can define my custom permission to adds more.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("erp_view_company", "Can see the company information"),
            ("erp_edit_company", "Can edit the company information"),
            ("erp_delete_company", "Can delete the company"),
        )
```

When you migrate, these permissions are automatically created at DB level. How can you retrieve all the permissions from a model?

```
# retrieves the permissions
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(get_all_permissions_of_model_Company)
# adds permissions to group
group = Group.objects.create(name='foo', permissions=permissions)
# adds user to group
user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: Note that as of Django 2.1, [each Model has 4 default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions). `view_model` was added.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would suggest you something like this:

```
all_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='app label', content_type__model='lower case model name')
```

Retrieving model's `app_label`:

```
Company._meta.app_label
```

Retrieving model's lower case name:

```
Company._meta.model_name
```

Also, you can [retrieve a `ContentType` instance representing a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model):

```
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Company)
```

Since `ContentType` uses a cache, it is quite acceptable. Thus, there is another way to achieve what you need:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Company)
all_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
```

Comment: can you please help me to filter only custom permissions for the model

Comment: @SandeepPrasadKushwaha The first thing that comes to my mind is to filter permissions by [the `codename` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission.codename). If that doesn't work for you please go ahead and post a separate question for that (in case it doesn't exist already).

Answer (score 3):

you can check on `codename` field which will be something like: `'change_company'` etc ...

```
model_name = 'company'
all_perms_on_this_modal = Permission.objects.filter(codename__contains=model_name)
```

Comment: I just saw that the table permissions has a contentt_ype_id that is the foreign key of the values in the table django_content_type. Instead of using the codename, is not better to use the model?

Comment: @realnot I would not use contenttype, with codename there is no joins, so it is cheaper

Comment: This will fail at least in 2 cases: 2 models with the same name in different applications and one model's permission containing another model's name.

Comment: @doniyor I think **ErnestTen** is right. From the query I get: [<Permission: account | company employee | Can add company employee>, <Permission: account | company employee | Can change company employee>, <Permission: account | company employee | Can delete company employee>, <Permission: erp | company | Can add company>, <Permission: erp | company | Can change company>, <Permission: erp | company | Can delete company>, <Permission: erp | company group | Can add company group>, <Permission: erp | company group | Can change company group>, ... This doesn't mean necessarily a bad model design.

Comment: @realnot ok you are right. then you should go for Ernest's suggested solution. and sorry Ernest, I didnot think to the end while answering here, you are absolutely right

Comment: I propose to accept the @ErnestTen as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve this without touching the database, using the Meta class instead. Django gives you everything you need, but it takes a little arm twisting.

```
codenames = [t[0] for t in Company._meta.permissions]
for action in Company._meta.default_permissions:
    codenames.append(f'{action}_{Company._meta.model_name}')
print(codenames)
```

This should give a coherent list like:

```
['erp_view_company',
 'erp_edit_company',
 'erp_delete_company',
 'add_company',
 'change_company',
 'delete_company',
 'view_company']
```

So in my case, there are many scenarios where I want a list of valid codenames *to create a query*, and it's not reasonable to have someone execute multiple queries in that process if it is performance-sensitive.